# Cloudinary Elixir Phoenix integration

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, cloudinary

Has anyone of you discovered/written a way to use cloudinary with Elixir? All of their integrations i saw were based on Cloudinary's plugin. But i haven't saw a plugin for neither elixir or erlang.

Is there a way to easily fabricate their method of sending requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a look at this.

https://github.com/sschneider1207/ExCloudinary

Very simple library, easy to incorporate to your project. When you want to upload image call ExCloudinary.uploadImage(image.path) where image is your Phoenix's multipart.

Answer (score 3):

for anybody looking for something a bit more recent. It seems the most popular option is this one
https://github.com/smeevil/cloudex